# Rails run job only once on application startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a polling job in Rails that pings a server every X seconds.

I'm using Sidekiq/Redis to execute this background job.

I want this job to be executed once every X seconds from application startup until application is killed. Whenever I start the server again, I clear it's Sidekiq queue and start a new job

What I thought was to put it in an initializer **config/initializers/my_app_start.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq/api' # for the case of rails console

module MyAppModule
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.after_initialize do
            SidekiqProcess.start! unless SidekiqProcess.is_running?
            
            Sidekiq::Queue.new("online_orders").clear
            # it calls itself after X seconds in "after_perform" callback
            OnlineOrdersJob.perform_later("fetch")

            Sidekiq::Queue.new("tunnelin").clear
            TunnelinJob.perform_later("reload")
        end
    end
end
```

and this is **my app/lib/sidekiq.rb**

```
class SidekiqProcess

    def self.is_running?
        return system("ps aux | grep '[s]idekiq'")
    end

    def self.start!
        system("ruby " + ENV['APP_ROOT'] + "/bin/sidekiq_up.rb &")
    end

    def self.get_pid
        pid = `ps aux | grep sidekiq | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
        if pid.present?
            pid = pid.split("\n")[0]
        end
        return pid
    end

    def self.stop
        pid = self.get_pid
        if pid == nil || pid == ""
            return "sidekiq pid not found"
        end
        return system("kill -HUP " + pid)
    end
    def self.stop!
        pid = self.get_pid
        if pid == nil || pid == ""
            return "sidekiq pid not found"
        end
        return system("kill -9 " + pid)
    end
end
```

Problem is: It's running 3 times. I assume it's because my rails server config creates 3 workers and each worker will execute all initializers. How to ensure an initializer runs only once, regardless of number of workers?

Comment: Did you consider using a gem like [`sidekiq-scheduler`](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) when you want to run a job on a fixed schedule?

Comment: Second for ``sidekiq-scheduler``. Don't let the description that it 'mimics cron' put you off; unlike ``cron`` it handles sub-minute intervals nicely.